# Android Retrofit log does not show

Tags: android, logging, retrofit2, okhttp

Retrofit does not print log. Log level set to verbose. Tried HttpLoggingInterceptor too.

using these gradles

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
```

**Code**

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
httpClient.newBuilder().connectTimeout(6, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(6, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(6, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request original = chain.request();
                        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                .header("Authorization", "aDRF@F#JG_a34-n3d")
                                .method(original.method(), original.body());
                        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                        return chain.proceed(request);
                    }
                })
    .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);


return httpClient;
```

Comment: U added OkHttpClient to Retrofit?

Comment: Maybe you have found answer to your problem?

Comment: @sanevys yes... I have marked a answer as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact I don't know why you don't see logs, but here is part of my code which works fine:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(logging);

String creditentials = username + ":" + password;
_base64 = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creditentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

Interceptor authorization = chain -> {
    Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", _base64)
            .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            .build();
    return chain.proceed(newRequest);
};

httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(authorization);

_retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(API_URL)
        .client(httpClientBuilder.build())
        .build();
```

Answer (score 5):

In some cases you need to allow extended logs on certain physical android devices.
This can be done in developers menu in the android phone settings.

Answer (score 5):

On some devices (emulator or real Android ones) logging is by default disabled. You need to enable this option to see the logs.
Tried this with Meizu M3s.

1. Go to **Developer Options**.
2. Find **Performance optimization**.
3. Find **Advanced logging**.
4. Allow all.

Please note that for different devices the steps might be slightly different.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I forgot to call `setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC)` and it was implicitly set to `NONE` by default.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with not seeing OkHttp network logs when Log buffer in Developer options on my emulator was set to Off, so after I changed to any other value, for example, 16m and tried again, it displayed logs correctly.